# Why is my c# class function return showing red squiggly?

Tags: c#

I'm a VB.net coder for quite a few years now. I have recently been pushed into learning C# due to software companies changing default SDK's over to C#. I don't mind a challenge. I do have an issue with this Array function that I'm currently working on. I think I have the variables called out properly and my If statements structured right. My only problem is that there is a red squiggly line under the return variable at the end of the code block. The red squiggly means that I have something wrong or have the return syntax incorrect. I do not see where I have it wrong, so I asking for a second opinion.

Here is the Code Class. What this class does is receive an Integer from a form and it is supposed to return a double with a 4 to 5 place decimal.

```
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Text;
    using System.Threading.Tasks;
    using static System.Math;

    namespace CarterCalculationTools
    {
        public class FcmValue
        {
            public int FcmVal(int[] NeeNum)
            {
                var arrFcmVal = new double[61];
                double fcmResult;

                arrFcmVal[6] = 6276;
                arrFcmVal[7] = 7014.48155;
                arrFcmVal[8] = 7553.5088;
                arrFcmVal[9] = 7927.82976;
                arrFcmVal[10] = 8210.66384;
                arrFcmVal[11] = 8407.07949;
                arrFcmVal[12] = 8544.72716;
                arrFcmVal[13] = 8649.93887;
                arrFcmVal[14] = 8707.52206;
                arrFcmVal[15] = 8750.81112;
                arrFcmVal[16] = 8771.81307;
                arrFcmVal[17] = 8777.41987;
                arrFcmVal[18] = 8770.4081;
                arrFcmVal[19] = 8755.49639;
                arrFcmVal[20] = 8735.9733;
                arrFcmVal[21] = 8712.949;
                arrFcmVal[22] = 8679.01338;
                arrFcmVal[23] = 8644.57568;
                arrFcmVal[24] = 8611.92784;
                arrFcmVal[25] = 8575.37948;
                arrFcmVal[26] = 8542.55544;
                arrFcmVal[27] = 8495.9123;
                arrFcmVal[28] = 8451.60508;
                arrFcmVal[29] = 8409.80863;
                arrFcmVal[30] = 8370.20725;
                arrFcmVal[31] = 8334.23982;
                arrFcmVal[32] = 8293.85668;
                arrFcmVal[33] = 8252.51027;
                arrFcmVal[34] = 8214.39145;
                arrFcmVal[35] = 8177.75277;
                arrFcmVal[36] = 8135.08678;
                arrFcmVal[37] = 8095.31568;
                arrFcmVal[38] = 8058.21202;
                arrFcmVal[39] = 8023.5711;
                arrFcmVal[40] = 7986.15127;
                arrFcmVal[41] = 7949.5622;
                arrFcmVal[42] = 7915.15875;
                arrFcmVal[43] = 7882.78926;
                arrFcmVal[44] = 7852.31547;
                arrFcmVal[45] = 7822.26029;
                arrFcmVal[46] = 7786.75829;
                arrFcmVal[47] = 7753.07449;
                arrFcmVal[48] = 7721.09674;
                arrFcmVal[49] = 7690.72174;
                arrFcmVal[50] = 7661.85424;
                arrFcmVal[51] = 7634.40623;
                arrFcmVal[52] = 7608.29631;
                arrFcmVal[53] = 7578.34532;
                arrFcmVal[54] = 7547.26788;
                arrFcmVal[55] = 7517.52062;
                arrFcmVal[56] = 7489.03351;
                arrFcmVal[57] = 7461.74129;
                arrFcmVal[58] = 7435.58307;
                arrFcmVal[59] = 7410.50192;
                arrFcmVal[60] = 7386.44464;
                arrFcmVal[64] = 7291.45697;     

                if (Enumerable.Range(6,60).Contains(FcmVal(NeeNum)))
                {   fcmResult = arrFcmVal[FcmVal(NeeNum)];

                }
                else if (FcmVal(NeeNum) == 64)
                {
                    fcmResult = arrFcmVal[FcmVal(NeeNum)];
                }

                else
                {                         
                   fcmResult = -1;
                }
                return fcmResult;
            }
        }
    }
```

=UPDATE=
Here is the finished code for populating a textbox with data from a SQL table:

```
public void FcmValue()
    {
        string ConString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConString"].ConnectionString;
        string str = "SELECT [fcmVal] FROM [CalcTools].[dbo].[FcmValue] WHERE [neeNumCount] = @neeNumCount";
        using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConString))
        {
            //using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("sp_frmNeedleCalc_FcmValue", con))
            using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(str, con))
            {
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@neeNumCount", nudNeeNum.Value);

                if (con != null && con.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
                {
                    con.Open();
                }
                SqlDataReader rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();

                while (rdr.Read())
                {
                    string fcmFactor = rdr["fcmVal"].ToString();
                    txtFcmFactor.Text = fcmFactor;
                }
                con.Close();
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: What's the error message? Check the Error List pane or just hover over the red squiggly line.

Comment: You are trying to return a `double` when your method returns an `int`

Comment: Check this line : `public int FcmVal(int[] NeeNum)`

Comment: I did change the variable NeeNum to neeNum to comply as camel-case. and changed 'var arrFcmVal =  new double[64];' to 'var arrFcmVal =  new double[55];'

Comment: Won't this also cause a StackOverflow because of your recursion here: `if (Enumerable.Range(6,60).Contains(FcmVal(NeeNum)))`

Comment: Can you explain requirement properly , and you are  trying to return double value , and checking in array index this completely invalid operation.

Comment: Try to build it. Read the error. You don't have to guess, it will tell you exactly what it thinks is wrong.

Comment: I deleted my answer, as your code doesn't make any sense. Maybe if you explain what the method must do we could help further

Comment: @Pikoh I stated in my original question a description of what the class is for

Comment: @Darren Young Yes the Enumerable.Range will not work on a double so I have to change the condition to something else. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your method returns an int, and fcmResult is of type double. Red squigly is there because double cannot be implicitly converted to int. Your method should return double.

Comment: Yes, this is the reason the red squigglies appeared now I know! Thanks! I'm currently in the process of changing my conditions in the "if, then else" to work with a double. I will post the finished code so others may benefit.

Comment: See the update in the original question to view the finished code.